# How to pass props to css class in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I must create a generic toast component with a custom message and class. I managed to pass a message props without problems but I still can't do it with the bootstrap class.

child: Toast.vue

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  message:{
    type:String,
    default:'Mon message'
  },
  class:{
    type:String,
    default:'text-bg-info'
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3">
    <div ref="toast1" id='showToast' class="toast" :class={{props.class}} role="alert">
      <div class="toast-body">
        <span>{{ props.message }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Parent Home.vue:

````
<script setup>
import Form from '../components/Form.vue'
import Toast from '../components/Toast.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <main class="mt-5">
    <Form />
    <Toast
    message="Created"
    class="text-bg-success"
    ></Toast>
  </main>
</template>
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an error in my template code in child component when I pass class props:

````
<template>
  <div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3">
    <div ref="toast1" id='showToast' class="toast" :class="props.class" role="alert">
      <div class="toast-body">
        <span>{{ props.message }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```
````

Answer (score 2):

`class` is a [fallthrough attribute](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html) and it's passed directly without the need to declare it as prop, so to avoid the behavior you should [prevent inheriting that attribute](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance) :

```
<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false
}
</script>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  message:{
    type:String,
    default:'Mon message'
  },
})
</script>

<template>
  <div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3">
    <div ref="toast1" id='showToast' class="toast" :class="$attrs.class" role="alert">
      <div class="toast-body">
        <span>{{ message }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You're welcome, not also that props are automatically unwrapped in template, so you should use `{{message}}` instead of `{{props.message}}`